# Reloading UrlRewrite middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I have some very basic code for doing url rewrites inside of a dotnetcore app.  I'm using .net 6.  I'd  like to be able to reload these urls when the IISUrlRewrite file changes.  It's easy enough to use fileProvider.Watch to watch for changes, but calling app.UseRewriter again doesn't seem like it work since it'd put it at the end of the pipeline.  Any ideas short of rolling my own rewrite middleware?

```
        var fileProvider = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IFileProvider>();
        var options = new RewriteOptions().AddIISUrlRewrite(fileProvider, "IISUrlRewrite.xml");
        app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Comment: One possible way is writing a custom url rewrite middleware to read the file each time when the request come in. Or write a background task to monitor the xml file changed and then restart the application .